Show that $K_{a \times b}$ is a robust expander.
Let $\nu, \tau>0$, $G$ be a graph on $n$ vertices. We define a $\nu$-robust neighbourhood $RN_{\nu,G}(S)$ of a set $S \subset V(G)$ in $G$ to be the set of vertices of $G$ which has at least $\nu n$ neighbours in $S$. We say that $G$ is a robust $(\nu,\tau)$ expander if $|RN_{\nu,G}(S)| \geq |S|+\nu n$ for each $S \subset V(G)$ satisfying $\tau n \leq |S| \leq (1-\tau)n$.
In paper [1], B. Garnet and F. Joos claimed that the balanced complete $a$-partite graph $K_{a \times b}$ is a robust expanders when $a \geq 3$. I believe what Garnet and Joos mean is that for all $\tau>0$, there exist a sufficiently small $\nu >0$ such that $K_{a \times b}$ is a robust $(\nu,\tau)$ expander. I try to prove the result by finding $\nu$ as a function of $\tau$, i.e. $\nu = \nu(\tau)$ that also possibly includes the parameter $a$. However, I cannot give such a function.
I do not know why it is true that for $a\geq 3$, $K_{a \times b}$ is a robust expander. I also do not know why this is not the case when $a=2$.
[1] B. Granet and F. Joos, Random perfect matchings in regular graphs, Random Struct. Alg. 64 (2024), 3–14. https://doi.org/10.1002/rsa.21172
